# Flatness of submodules of free modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Are submodules of free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules flat? if not what conditions on $G$ makes it true? $G$ is an infinite group.

If $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a Prüfer domain then this is true. Can a group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ be a Prüfer domain?

In my case $G=GL_n(A)$ for $A=k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/I$ for some field $k$ and prime ideal $I$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The augmentation ideal of $\mathbb Z[G]$ is flat if and only if $H_i(G, \mathbb Z) = 0$ for all $i > 1$. I think this should rule out most cases of $GL_n(A)$, since these groups generally have interesting and nontrivial homology.